# What meanings does "a year's worth of savings" have?

Tags: meaning

[stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56901/meaning-of-a-functions-worth-of-code/56903#56903):
**(1)** "*a year's worth of savings*"
means
**(2)** "*all the savings you would save in a year's time*"

my variant:
**(3)** "*the savings you need to live for a year*"

Can (1) also mean (3)?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the answer in the linked question and would say that your "the savings you need to live for a year" is the usual meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 2. If you don't save enough for a year (like if you work at a minimum wage job) then you wouldn't have enough savings to survive. Hence you wouldn't have the savings you need to live for a year.